# Missing 'Open Source', 'Apps & Software' sections in 'My Profile' on SO Careers

Tags: support, jobs

For some reasons I don't have the 'OPEN SOURCE' and 'APPS & SOFTWARE' sections under 'My Profile' page on SO Careers.

Just on a side note, I'm not looking for a job so my SO Careers profile is '**Private**'. I mainly use my SO Careers profile for answering, suggesting UI changes and reporting bugs. It's only '19% complete' but I used to see the 'OPEN SOURCE' and 'APPS & SOFTWARE' sections even with this level of completion.

Here is what I see now:

> [image]

As you can see in the above screenshot, all I have now is 'JOB STATUS',  'TECHNOLOGIES', 'EXPERIENCE' and 'EDUCATION' sections below the 'Personal Statement'.

How do I get the 'OPEN SOURCE' and 'APPS & SOFTWARE' sections back in my profile?

P.S.

I can reproduce this in Chrome Ver. 45.0.2454.101 (64-bit), Firefox Ver. 41.0.1 and Safari Ver. Version 9.0 (10601.1.56.2) on my MacBook Pro Retina; OS X Yosemite Ver. 10.10.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is part of a UI change we're testing out. To consider your profile passing the required minimum for being classified as a non-abandoned profile, we require that you fill out a personal statement, at least two tags, and at least one entry under education or experience.

Until that threshold is met, we're currently trying out hiding all the other fields since for most people the extra fields are just extra noise right now.

The threshold is mostly used for determining if your profile shows up in our candidate search product, and since your CV is set to private this will never be the case, so it's worth looking into and seeing if we should not do this test for profiles that are set to private like yours.

Comment: If you're now with the Careers team..... who's working on the android app?? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not actually on the careers team, just helping out with some things across the company that interest me :)

Comment: Wow, you're cross-team developer! :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard lol exactly why I came to see this question: 'answered... **Kasra Rahjerdi**' -- mindblown :P

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Thanks but as you mentioned in the answer Private profile should be excluded... Would surely help me and others in case of answering issues, UI suggestions and bug reports.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It took two days for me to file this report. I even contacted you and few others to confirm... But, at least we know now that some sort of A/B test is in the progress as for SO Careers profiles goes. I still have to find other one though.